# Vue JS JEST test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex

I have a strange behaviour when trying to run a JEST unit test.

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import communicationPreferences from '@/pages/account/communication-preferences'

describe('Communication Preferences Page', () => {

  it('should render page', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(communicationPreferences)
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Page: communication-preferences.vue

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapState('account', ['communicationPreferences']),
    // communicationPreferenceTypeEmail() {
    //   return this.communicationPreferences.filter((e) => e.type === 'EMAIL')
    // },
    // communicationPreferenceTypeNotEmail() {
    //   return this.communicationPreferences.filter((e) => e.type !== 'EMAIL')
    // },
  },
```

When I run `npm run test` with computed lines above uncomment I get the error below but when I comment them out I have a successful test pass.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
  127 |     ...mapState('account', ['communicationPreferences']),
  128 |     communicationPreferenceTypeEmail() {
> 129 |       return this.communicationPreferences.filter((e) => e.type === 'EMAIL')
      | ^
  130 |     },
  131 |     communicationPreferenceTypeNotEmail() {
  132 |       return this.communicationPreferences.filter((e) => e.type !== 'EMAIL')
```

Cannot read property 'state' of undefined but I don't understand why, anything obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when trying `mapState` (or other `mapXXX` Vuex utilities) without an initialized Vuex store.

#### Solution

One way to fix this is to pass in the store via the [`global.plugins` mounting option](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-plugins):

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import communicationPreferences from '@/pages/account/communication-preferences'
import store from '@/store'

describe('Communication Preferences Page', () => {
  it('should render page', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(communicationPreferences,
      {   
        global: {
          plugins: [store], 
        },
      }
    )
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-init-vuex-for-jest?file=tests%2Funit%2FMyComponent.spec.js)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can init the Vuex store in your test setup.

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';


 beforeEach(() => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
})
```